# why dont we create emulater with most resent version and most oldest version

Tags: android, android-emulator

What if we use a emulator that is with most recent and oldvertion of sdk , what are the pros and cons?
I have notice some people tend to use only latest version instead of giving lower version for the backward compatibility. what I know is if we dont use backward compatibility , some phones can not use the application with latest sdk.

If we use only latest version how does it impacts on the application? If we go more deeper in backward compatibility, does it causes to the application perfomance or GUI reductions?

plz give me your idea.
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test on all API levels that your app supports (ideally on actual devices and not just emulator) and not just the oldest and newest versions. I would also prioritize testing on devices with API level 10 since it is currently the most common API version (http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: +1 for version 10 being most common. Also there seem to be quirks to certain releases that mean a commercial app really needs testing on many versions. Certainly Jelly Bean, ICS, and GingerBread at the minimium. There comes a point where you will have to sacrifice compatability, current trend seems to be 2.2 and up for testing.

Comment: thanks for the reply. If we go more deeper in backward compatibility such as less than 2.2 , does it cause to reduce features in api 10 since some features is api 10 doesnt suppot in old versions?

Comment: The older the version you use the less libraries/features you are likely to have. But, if you need a feature for your application and you aren't cutting off most of your potential clients, then use that version I guess. If I had to test, personally, I'd try 2.2, 2.3, 2.3.3, 4.0.3 and 4.1 at the minimum, that would cover most of the phone market. Then maybe a version of honeycomb if applicable. It really depends on the app and what you need. Google Now for example, only works on JellyBean so if you used an api with that, then you could only work in 4.1, far from ideal (just a hypothetical eg)

Comment: thanks. It means we have to create app that supports many versions if we don't focus speciall group or client in the market.